# Any better alternative to std::vector<std::unique_ptr<T>>?

Tags: c++, performance, c++11, vector, containers

I'm looking for a container *(targeted towards game-development, especially for entity management)* that needs to satisfy these requirements:

1. **Fast iteration**
2. **No copies of stored elements**
3. **No invalidation of pointers to the elements**
4. **Removal and insertion of elements**

Example:

```
Container<Entity> container;

// This pointer will always point to the player
Entity* player{new Entity};          
container.add(player);               

// Set some entities to "dead"
for(auto& e : container) if(e->type == "Enemy") e->die(); 

// Use erase-remove idiom on "dead" entities
container.cleanup();                 

// Player pointer is still valid
player->doSomething();
```

---

I've tried two different container types so far:

- `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<T>>`

  1. **Cache-friendly** (fast iteration)
  2. **No copies** (thanks to `std::unique_ptr`)
  3. **No invalidation of pointers** (thanks to `std::unique_ptr`)

...and...

- `std::list<T>`

  1. **Non cache-friendly** (slower iteration)
  2. **No copies**
  3. **No invalidation of pointers**

Even if it seems counter-intuitive, `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<T>>` is more performant than `std::list<T>` [according to my benchmarks](https://gist.github.com/SuperV1234/8098965).

*(For bigger types, `std::list<T>` is more performant during insertion, but `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<T>>` still wins)*.

---

I was wondering if there is a better alternative to `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<T>>`.

Ideally, the alternative should be **cache-friendly**, for fast iteration, and allow the user to refer to the same items even after adding/removing existing items **(pointers should not be invalidated)**.

Comment: Why do you need an alternative to vector which is already performing well?

Comment: Have you tried `std::deque`?  You'll get many of the same benefits you get from `std::vector`, but won't require a massive amount of contiguous memory for large amounts of data.

Comment: What operation are you going to perform more frequently?

Comment: I doubt the performance will be better, but you can try [`boost::ptr_vector<T>`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/ptr_container/doc/ptr_vector.html).

Comment: @AndyProwl: I'm gonna insert and remove elements every frame, and iterate the whole vector every frame.

Comment: @juanchopanza How would removal of elements work in an `std::array<T>`? Gaps would be left between elements. And if I shift every elements towards the beginning of the array, pointers will be invalidated.

Comment: You haven't said anything about removal of elements in your list of requirements.

Comment: @VittorioRomeo `std::array` works just like a C-style array. There's no such a thing as "remove elements" in an array.

Comment: Hmm, be careful mutating the structure every frame. That sort of thing can easily become slow, vs. swapping elements around, re-using elements, multiple independent containers instead of one big one, flags, etc.

Comment: @VittorioRomeo: In case you can find an upper bound on the number of objects you are going to create, you could some kind of [Object Pool pattern](http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/object-pool.html) and avoid owning pointers

Comment: @juanchopanza, Jefffrey: sorry, added removal as one of the requirements.

Comment: @Cameron, what alternative would you suggest?

Comment: Why do you use the erase-remove idiom for `std::list`? (Wouldn't that even change the addresses to the elements?) If you instead erase from the list in the loop where you let the enemies die, you get rid of the second time-consuming iteration on the `list`. According to my benchmarks, collapsing `LIST ITR` and `LIST REM DEAD` into one loop is about as fast as `VEC UPTR ITR` and `VEC UPTR REM DEAD` combined. Still, I'm not sure *why* `LIST ITR` is 1.5 times slower than `VEC UPTR ITR`.

Comment: (As far as I can see, your gist is missing several includes and the definition of `state`. I've added the includes for `<vector>` and `SSVUtils/SSVUtils.hpp` as well as a global `volatile bool state {false};`)

Comment: An invasive list ought to give as good performance, except for random access.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are doing the right thing by performance testing.  That is the only true way to answer this question.

The only thing I know of that might be faster is to to create a buffer.  Then create a custom allocator for the `vector<unique_ptr<T>, custom_allocator<unique_ptr<T>>>` which allocates from your buffer.

Also allocate your objects from the same buffer (such that the unique_ptr's point into the buffer).

To do this you would have to know upper limits, or write overflow logic for when your limits are exceeded.

Have the custom allocator grow from the middle of the buffer upwards.

Have the allocation for the unique_ptrs grow from the middle of the buffer downwards.

As long as the entire buffer fits in a cache line, you'll be fast as possible.  This is not trivial to implement and your current solution may well be good enough.

Answer (score 1):

That sounds like if a plain std::vector is what you want.

It is by far the fastest iteration possible as you are doing one sweep over a continuous part of the memory. You can only do better by looking into the structure of T.

Inserting new elements can be done using push_back in O(1). Deleting a single element can be done with a combination of swap and pop_back in O(1). Deleting several elements can be done using a combination of remove_if and erase.

You can not store pointers as they will be invalidated. However, what you can do is store the index and make the vector nearly globally available.

Using indices instead of pointers has two further advantages:

1. ints use 4 bytes whereas pointers use 8 bytes. Using pointers automatically leads to a larger memory footprint and thus to more cache misses. I doubt that you will have more than 2^32 entities so 8 bytes are overkill.
2. You can use a structure of arrays instead of an array of structures.

To illustrate point 2 look at the following two examples

```
struct Unit{
    int type, health;
};
vector<Unit>units;
for(int i=0; i<(int)units.size(); ++i)
    if(units[i].type == medic)
        units[i].health += 10;
```

vs

```
vector<int>type, health;
for(int i=0; i<(int)type.size(); ++i)
    if(type[i] == medic)
        health[i] += 10;
```

Suppose that there are only very few medics. In the first code snippet the whole memory has to be piped through the cache as types and health values are adjacent in memory. In the second example only all types have to be loaded and the few health values of the medics. In the sum less memory has to be loaded, which leads to faster iteration.